# SharePoint Calendar events display to particular users only

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint calendar events needs to display only for particular users only. I have added a People and group column in Calendar list.. and get the users from that column.. after that i don't know how to change the permission for those users? Those users only can view the events.
Can i set the permission in code behind. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {  SPListItem fromListItems = properties.ListItem;                      
            properties.ListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
            UpdateListItems(properties);
            base.ItemAdded(properties);           
    }

    private void UpdateListItems(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPWeb currentWeb;
        using (currentWeb = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            try
            {
                SPUser spLookUpUser = null;
                SPFieldLookupValue fieldLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(properties.ListItem["user"].ToString());
                string lookupValues = fieldLookupValue.LookupValue;
                SPFieldLookupValueCollection fieldLoodUpValueCollection = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection(properties.ListItem["user"].ToString());
                foreach (SPFieldLookupValue lookupValue in fieldLoodUpValueCollection)
                {
                    string lookUpUser = lookupValue.LookupValue;
                    spLookUpUser = currentWeb.EnsureUser(lookUpUser);
                    SPPrincipal assignee = (SPPrincipal)spLookUpUser;
                    GrantPermission(properties.ListItem, currentWeb, SPRoleType.Reader, assignee);                     

                }

                properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

      private static void GrantPermission(SPListItem CurrentListItem, SPWeb oSPWeb,             SPRoleType SPRoleType, SPPrincipal SPPrincipal)
    {
        try
        {               
            SPRoleDefinition oSPRoleDefinition = oSPWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType);               
            SPRoleAssignment oSPRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(SPPrincipal);             
            oSPRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(oSPRoleDefinition);             
            CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(oSPRoleAssignment);                
            CurrentListItem.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is to create your own ListItemReceiver and handling ItemAdded and ItemUpdated events. While handling these event you can setup rights according to your column. Disadvantage of this solution is that each event will have its own permission set. There's in MSDN limit that there should not be more than 5000 items in single list with individual permission set. Here is simple sample how to set item permissions (for current user in this case):

```
SPRoleDefinition roldDef = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
SPRoleAssignment rolAssign = new SPRoleAssignment(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser);
rolAssign.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roldDef);
if (!event.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) {
    event.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
    event.RoleAssignments.Add(rolAssign);
}
```

There's one potential issue of this code. User changing the item must have enough rights to change item's permissions. To ensure this it's good to wrap that code in SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges delegate.

Other possibility is to create the view filtering calendar events by your column. This cannot be done in UI (you can not specify  CAML operator in query) but can be done in SharePoint Designer. Advantage of this solution is that it is easier and less resource consuming as all events have inherited rights.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.. I almost get a way to reach my requirements from your reply. I couldn't understand the 'event' from your code.. but i'l try you code.. Once again thank you..

Comment: Event is variable containg edited calendar event processed in EventHandler. You can get it by SPListItem event = properties.ListItem

Answer (score 0):

you can using this feature. http://permissionmanagement.codeplex.com/
The solution allow you to create a rule permission to any type of list dynamically (from column). In your case, you assign permission to users defined in the column item.

if you want to optimize you application (5000 items with single permission), you can using the some logic but you create for each user a folder (having a single permission) and move the items to here folder.